# How to build a 4 to 16 decoder using ONLY TWO 2 to 4 decoders?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, decoder

Help please, I am new to circuits and decoders and I need some serious help.

How to build a 4x16 decoder using ONLY two 2x4 decoders?

Following the steps we took in the lecture, we are supposed to build a 4x16 decoder. So here taking k to be 4, k is even, so we will have \$2^k\$ so \$2^4 = 16\$ AND gates & 2 decoders each of size \$2^{k/2}\$ so \$2^2 = 4\$.

So we have 16 AND gates & two 2x4 decoders. Each 2x4 decoder has 4 AND gates so we have 8 AND gates that should be connected to the 16 AND gates, how do I do that?

Comment: You are allowed to use any number of AND gates and 2 2x4 decoders?

Comment: we are supposed to use 16 AND gates and two 2x4 decoders..

Comment: With 2 decoders and 16 ANDs it is easy.

Answer (score 4):

A \$2\$-by-\$4\$ decoder has two input lines and four output lines, only one of which is logical \$1\$ at any time.  Which line is \$1\$ depends on the input bit pair which can be \$00, 01, 10, 11\$.

So take two such \$2\$-by-\$4\$ decoders which give you four input lines. Let the
output lines be \$a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3\$ for one decoder and \$b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3\$
for the other.  Use the \$16\$ AND gates to compute the \$16\$ functions
\$ a_i \wedge b_j, 0 \leq i \leq 3, 0 \leq j \leq 3\$.  We now have a \$4\$-by-\$16\$
circuit with the property that only one output is a logical \$1\$ at any time: which one depends on the values of $i$ and $j$ which
in turn depend on the \$4\$ input bits.  In other words, we have a \$4\$-by-\$16\$ decoder
constructed from two \$2\$-by-\$4\$ decoders and \$16\$ AND gates.

Comment: An easy way to visualize this is as a matrix: the first decoder selects the column, the second decoder selects the rows, and the AND gates - one at each junction of the matrix - are enabled if and only if the row and column are both selected.

Comment: If the decoders are used to operate LEDs, one could omit the gates if one decoder has active-high outputs that are capable of sourcing current sufficient for the LEDs, and the other has active-low outputs.  Simply wire the LEDs in a matrix, and each LED will only light when the "active-high-output" decoder is outputting high and the "active-low-output" decoder is outputting low.

Comment: @supercat As the saying goes, there is more than one way to skin a cat. In this case, the desired solution was required to use 16 AND gates (and presumably two _identical_ \$2\$-by-\$4\$ decoders) .....

Answer (score 3):

you would need 5 such decoders. re-check your notes
[image]

The question does not prohibit use of logic other than decoders so using 16 2-input and gates we have the following circuit that fulfils the requirement (Muzammal Baig)
[image]

Comment: i checked them again , and it says we must use only two 2 to 4 decoders knowing that we won't use the E ( enable input ) because it is a beginner course.

Comment: pretty hard to create 16 outputs with only 2x4=8

Comment: exactly that is my point ... I kept trying but to no use ..

Comment: I guess your assumptions need to be validated

Comment: Tony Stewart what software did you use to make those diagrams?